# Aggregate (group) data in Excel online (M365) and keep it updated

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I have an Excel table with some customer names. Those customer names are not unique. On tope of that there's a lot of data in other columns we need together with the customer names.

For another related purpose, I need a list of unique customer names and add a custom status for each customer. I want to have it in a separate table, because someone will have to add that status manually. Adding it in the original table would require more effort, because they'd have to add it to every occurrence of the customer.

The problem is that it needs to work in Excel Online (as part of M365) and the new table should be formatted as a table (not just some range). I've already created that new table using Power Query and it worked and was updated. However, as far as I can see it's not possible to refresh that query in Excel Online - it works only when opening the file in the app (not in the browser).

I've tried a Pivot Table, but then I can't add the status column.

I've also tried the UNIQUE formula that spills over, which kind of gives me the result I want and I can add columns as needed, but I can't format the range as a table (as spill is not available in a table).

Does anyone have an idea how I could get the unique customer names from my original table in a new table where I could add more custom columns? (Refresh could be done using an Office script and Power Automate.)

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Did you try the Advanced Filter?

Comment: @Lee as far as I understand the Advanced Filter it would give me the list of unique customer names, but to my knowledge there's no way to keep that list updated after that unless I filter it again.

Comment: I'm going to test another option: I'll add the state in the original table as a new column and then try with a Power Apps form to edit those values. So I'll have the logic in Power Apps to display a unique list of customers there with the status and changes through Power Apps are then propagated to all appropriate rows in the Excel. I'll post here if it works as I planned. :)

Comment: Just for completeness: I did as mentioned before and left the Excel table as is and added the column for status right there. In Power Apps I created a small app, that retrieves all customer names from Excel, where the user can select one or many of the customers and set the status. Then the app sends the information to Excel and saves it there for each row with the appropriate customer.
The additional benefit: Using PowerAutomate flows for the communication between app and Excel, I can have anyone editing the customer status without the need to give everyone access to my Excel database.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought was to suggest using UNIQUE outside a table as a dynamic spilled array. This would work well if you are willing to sacrifice the table requirement.

The power query option should work as long as your data source is from an excel workbook or an odata feed. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-query-data-sources-in-excel-versions-e9332067-8e49-46fc-97ff-f2e1bfa0cb16).

One potential problem: the customer name ans status is linked only via a common row number (which isnt a unique database key). If you happen to sort the source data or insert or delete customer lines, the order in which the unique names appear in the second sheet would change and no longer align with the correct status.

The best way to reliably deal with this issue is probably with VBA. Code a macro that would refresh the unique names list and merge it with the old status list (which contains static names copied as values not formulas). Alternatively you could try to only ever add to the bottom of the source list, or at least keep a copied and pasted "as value" names list in column C (column A is UNIQUE formula, B is status). This way you can at least sporadically check that A matches C and make manual corrections if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions and input, Mobus. Maybe I can find a workaround for the table requirement. I checked the link you provided and indeed it should work with Power Query - I haven't used Power Query yet in Excel (I know it from Power BI only) and maybe I'm doing something wrong, but neither OData feed nor Excel workbook allow me to refresh the query later. Even if I set up automated refresh in the Excel app, it throws an error in the browser version.